# RestAPI nextRecordsURL lifetime

Tags: rest-api, query

we are currently working on POC that queries large amounts records through RestAPI. For queries that exceed the batch query size, a nextRecordsURL gets returned. Does anyone know what the lifetime of this URL is?

e.g. "nextRecordsUrl" : "/services/data/v20.0/query/01gD0000002HU6KIAW-2000"

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/dome_query.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nextRecordsUrl is the same as a [query cursor](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_query_querylocator.htm) in the SOAP API, and so as such each user gets 10 with the least recently used getting expired when you reach the 10 limit, or if they haven't been used in 15 minutes. The 10 limit is shared across APIs, so that's 10 total between REST & SOAP, not 10 for REST & 10 for SOAP.