# nextRecordsUrl TTL: is it still 15 minutes? Error at expiry?

Tags: rest-api

I'm aware of [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38473/restapi-nextrecordsurl-lifetime), but I just tried a `nextRecordsUrl` from ~ 8 hours ago and it's still live.  Is the 15 minute lifetime still valid?

EDIT: When/if it expires, any idea what error is returned by the API?  I'd like to write some logic around that to kick off a fresh SOQL query when it happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QueryLocator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_querymore_querylocator.htm) cursors are good until they either (a) reach the end of the result set, (b) are bumped by a newer cursor, or (c) go 15 minutes *without being read*. Assuming none of those cases are true, perhaps the system simply hasn't bothered to clean up the cursor (which sounds like a bug, if you ask me). You definitely should not depend on your cursor waiting around for more than 15 minutes, and it could go away much sooner if that user is using a lot of different API calls. Should your QueryLocator go away for any reason, I expect it should return INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR in the errorCode parameter of the response, in which case you'll have to start your query over again.